# Enabling Direct Payments to Multiple Sellers Using Apple Pay: Is Interchanging Merchant IDs Feasible?

Tags: applepay, applepayjs

Is it possible to develop an application that utilizes Apple Pay to facilitate direct payments to multiple sellers by interchanging their merchant IDs? The aim is to enable the selling of digital assets without requiring each seller to have their own application. For example, if seller person A sells a digital asset to buyer person B, the transaction's merchant ID would be that of seller person A. Is it feasible to implement such a system using Apple Pay?

I explored the Apple Pay documentation to understand the available APIs and the flow of a typical payment transaction, from my understanding to acquire a merchant id you need to be on the apple developer program and that needs to be tied to your domain which means this is highly unrealistic.